# Question about the ergodic mean

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, limits-and-convergence, hilbert-spaces

This is a repost from [this MathStackExchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4837626/doubt-on-ergodic-mean), where unfortunately I was not able to resolve this question.

I've read a thesis where there is an example on ergodic mean, where however there is one point that is not fully clear to me, so hopefully someone can help me solve it.

Let's consider a quasi-local algebra $\mathcal{B}$ defined as norm closure of $\otimes_i \mathcal{A}_i$, where each $\mathcal{A}_i = \mathcal{A}$ is the algebra of bounded operators on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ (the index $i$ runs over the set of integer numbers). The element $x_i \in \mathcal{A}_i$ can be written as follows: $x_i = \otimes_{j<i}\mathcal{I}_j \otimes x \, \otimes_{k>i}\mathcal{I}_k$ where $\mathcal{I}$ is the identity. Let's consider the automorphism $\tau: \tau(x_i) = x_{i+1} $, and let's consider the tau-invariant state $\omega$. Then, in the thesis it is written that $ \frac{1}{2N + 1} \sum_{i=-N}^{N} x_i$ converges weakly to $\omega(x)\mathcal{I}$ as $N \to +\infty$.

My doubt is the following. Let's suppose that there are $y, z \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $[x, y] = z$. Then we can consider the operator $\sum_{i=-N}^{N} y_i$ such that $[\frac{1}{2N + 1} \sum_{i=-N}^{N} x_i, \sum_{j=-N}^{N} y_j] = \frac{1}{2N + 1} \sum_{i=-N}^{N} z_i$. If we take the limit $N \to \infty$ this commutator does not go to zero despite the fact that before we said that $ \frac{1}{2N + 1} \sum_{i=-N}^{N} x_i$ converges weakly to the identity operator. How is that possible? Maybe the operator $\sum_{j=-N}^{N} y_j$ does not converges weakly?

Comment: There’s no reason why $\sum_{j = -N}^N y_j$ has to converge weakly - it’s not uniformly bounded in norm, so there’s no reason why even a subsequence has to converge weakly.

Comment: @DavidGao I am not sure if it converges or not. A possible set of states where this operator may converges could be maybe $\omega (A) = Tr[\frac{e^{-\sum_{i=-N}^{N} y_{i}^{2}}}{Z}A]$ where Z is the trace of the exponential operator and A is any element of the algebra

Comment: What do you mean? Isn’t $\omega$ supposed to be a single $\tau$-invariant state? And how does defining a set of states tells you whether your sum converges or not? It’s not like the definition of $\mathcal{B}$ or $\sum_{j = -N}^N y_j$ depends on the choice of states.

Comment: @DavidGao you were just saying that there's no reason why it has to weakly. I was just telling you that states with an exponential decreases in the operators may be good enough. Of course, the actual question that I would like to solve is the following (I thought to be clear, but I was wrong): is the operator $\sum_j y_j$ always not convergent when the state $\omega$ is $\tau$-invariant? Or maybe the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: I can’t say for sure that it never converges weakly, but I would be surprised if it ever were. There’s another issue though - multiplication is not weakly continuous, so even if the sum were to converge, it doesn’t mean the commutators have to converge to the commutator of the limits.

Comment: @DavidGao can you please explain me a bit more on the weakly continuous of commutators? It is quite interesting, since I thought the commutator of the limits is equal to the limit of the commutator even with weakly convergence

Comment: Consider, for example, $A = \otimes_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (\mathbb{M}_2, \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{Tr})$. Let $X = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $Y = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Note that $[X, Y] = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ -2 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \neq 0$. For any $n > 1$, let $X_n = X \otimes 1 \otimes \cdots \otimes 1 \otimes Y \otimes 1 \otimes \cdots \in A$, where the $Y$ tensor component is at the $n$-th place…

Comment: Similarly, let $Y_n = Y \otimes 1 \otimes \cdots \otimes 1 \otimes Y \otimes 1 \otimes \cdots \in A$, where the second $Y$ tensor component is at the $n$-th place. Then $[X_n, Y_n] = [X, Y] \otimes 1 \otimes \cdots$ is independent of $n$ and nonzero, but both $X_n$ and $Y_n$ converge weakly to $0$. This shows that taking commutators is not weakly continuous.

Comment: (Maybe I should be more precise. Multiplication and therefore taking commutators are separately weakly continuous in both of its arguments. They’re just not *jointly* weakly continuous, which is what you need.)

Comment: Thank you @DavidGao, it's really food for my thoughts! Just to understand your example, $\frac{1}{2} Tr$ is the state acting on each $2x2$ matrix, and $X_n$ and $Y_n$ go weakly to 0 because they basically converge to $X\otimes1$ and $Y\otimes1$ which are traceless. Is my understanding correct? May I ask you if you have in mind another simple example where $X_n$ and $Y_n$ do not converge to 0 but to a well defined operator but their commutator goes to 0?

Comment: For the first question, yes, $\frac{1}{2} \mathrm{Tr}$ acts on each tensor component (that is, $\mathbb{M}_2$). The state acting on the infinite tensor product algebra is the infinite tensor state $\frac{1}{2} \mathrm{Tr} \otimes \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{Tr} \otimes \cdots$. The precise way to make sense of that tensor product is through the use of GNS construction, but the details don't matter too much.

Comment: For the second question, not exactly but more or less. $X_n = (X \otimes 1 \otimes \cdots)(1 \otimes \cdots \otimes 1 \otimes Y \otimes 1 \otimes \cdots)$. The first term is constant, and the second term converges weakly to $0$ because $Y$ is traceless. (This is because the tensor component $Y$ moves between different tensor position - sort of like if you have an infinite sequence of random variables all independent from each other, then weakly it's supposed to converge to the expectation, or, in this case, the trace, which is 0.)

Comment: Since multiplication is *separately* weakly continuous, you get $X_n$ converges weakly to 0. The same reasoning applies to $Y_n$. For the final question, you can sort of just alter the earlier example, say, let $X'_n = X_n + Y \otimes 1 \otimes \cdots$ and $Y'_n = Y_n - X \otimes 1 \otimes \cdots$. Then $X'_n$ weakly converges to $Y \otimes 1 \otimes \cdots$ and $Y'_n$ weakly converges to $-X \otimes 1 \otimes \cdots$, but $[X'_n, Y'_n] = [X_n, Y_n] + [Y \otimes 1 \otimes \cdots, Y_n] - [X_n, X \otimes 1 \otimes \cdots] - [X, Y] \otimes 1 \otimes \cdots = 0$.

Comment: So $[X'_n, Y'_n] \rightarrow 0 \neq [X, Y] \otimes 1 \otimes \cdots = [Y \otimes 1 \otimes \cdots, -X \otimes 1 \otimes \cdots]$.